# Unable to connect oracle database using cx_oracle from AWS Glue

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am trying to connect oracle database from AWS glue using cx_oracle but i am getting this error message

> DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help

I tried to downoad the so files as per the document and stored it in S3 which has been linked to Glue with --extra-files parameter but still getting same error message

I have tried this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57598027/connection-with-oracle-cx-oracle-problem-with-aws-glue-python-shell) and also tried to set rpath with s3 url but no success. Any idea would really help

Comment: In a question you've mentioned there's a point that symlinks are not supported and as an example libclntsh.so is given. I guess you can get some insights there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Credits

This answer is a compilation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59467059/15235078) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53981971/15235078) and a lot of discussion around the former in the comments. Credit for the `rpath` patching solution goes to @harjeet-singh, the original author of the abovementioned answer and for the `libaio` to @good-will, but there are still some steps around these solutions that keep confusing people, so that is why I am going to consolidate everything in a single step-by-step answer here.

## Background

In order to connect to an Oracle database using `cx-Oracle` from a Python shell AWS Glue job, we need to bundle the oracle client libraries with it. Furthermore, the libraries have to be patched with a correct `rpath` in order to load correctly, because in Glue runtime we have filesystem write access only to `/tmp`, which is where our archive will be, but `cx-Oracle` can't know that and expects a different directory by default. And the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` hack cannot be implemented because we have no control over how the Glue job is launched.

## Step-By-Step Guide

1. Download Instant Client Basic ZIP package for x86-64 Linux from [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html). This guide uses version 21.5.0.0.0

```sh
wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-basic-linuxx64.zip
```

2. Unzip the archive

```sh
unzip instantclient-basic-linuxx64.zip
```

3. Remove symlinks from the archive and move the file they point to (in this case `libclntsh.so.21.1` to the one that is going to be looked up when you use `cx-Oracle`: `libclntsh.so`). This is done because whatever loads these libraries dynamically apparently does not resolve symlinks. Maybe it will in the future, but I had to do this to make it work.

```sh
cd instantclient_21_5/
find . -type l -name "libclntsh.so*" -delete
mv libclntsh.so.21.1 libclntsh.so
```

Do the same with the other files with symlinks if after completing the whole guide and running your job you still have problems with libraries like

> DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libsomething.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

4. Patch the `rpath` to point to a static directory that we are going to be using from inside the Glue job
   For example, if your archive is named `instant-client-basic-linux.x64-21.5.0.0.0` and it contains a folder named `instantclient_21_5` with all the libraries. When the job runs, this archive is going to be available in a random directory under `/tmp` (more on that below. We need to find our archive in one of those directories and extract it to a static directory under `/tmp`, for example `/tmp/libs`. So then, your `rpath` would be `/tmp/libs/instant-client-basic-linux.x64-21.5.0.0.0/instantclient_21_5`, because that in the absolute path to client libraries.

```sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install patchelf -y
patchelf --set-rpath /tmp/libs/instant-client-basic-linux.x64-21.5.0.0.0/instantclient_21_5 libclntsh.so
```

5. Put `libaio.so.1` in the archive

```sh
cd ..
wget https://src.fedoraproject.org/lookaside/pkgs/libaio/libaio-0.3.110.tar.gz/2a35602e43778383e2f4907a4ca39ab8/libaio-0.3.110.tar.gz
tar xzvf libaio-0.3.110.tar.gz
cd libaio-0.3.110
make prefix=`pwd`/usr install 
find ./usr/lib/ -type l -name "libclntsh.so*" -delete
mv ./usr/lib/libaio.so.1.0.1 ../instantclient_21_5/libaio.so.1
```

**Note:** you might want to check with a newer version of `libaio` if there is one.
6. Zip the archive

```sh
cd ..
zip -T -r instantclient-basic-linuxx64_patched.zip instantclient_21_5/
```

7. Download `cx-Oracle` wheel

```sh
wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a9/b7/c2d0223fb4f1013b090cf82f3ce56f36f33b79a48f9c33b36717c2977b04/cx_Oracle-8.3.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
```

8. Upload the archive and `cx-Oracle` to S3

```sh
aws s3 cp instantclient-basic-linuxx64_patched.zip s3://<mybucket>/glue_libs
aws s3 cp cx_Oracle-8.3.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl s3://<mybucket>/glue_libs
```

9. Configure your Glue job

I assume your glue job is already created and we are going to just configure it.

- Put the S3 URL to the archive in "Referenced files path" configuration parameter
- Put the S3 URL to the `cx-Oracle` wheel in "Python library path" configuration parameter

10. Add a bit of code to the glue job to set up the libraries.
    This code must be executed before any usage of `cx-Oracle`. It can be executed after import, but before the usage.

Iterate through random directories in `/tmp`, find an archive you created and extract it to a static directory that we set in `rpath` previously. Then initialize the `cx-Oracle` client and you are good to go.
Here is an example of an implementation:

```py
import zipfile

from pathlib import Path

import cx_Oracle

filename = 'instantclient-basic-linuxx64_patched.zip'
oracle_archive = next(Path('./tmp').glob(f'**/{filename}'))
with zipfile.ZipFile(oracle_archive, 'r') as f:
    Path('./tmp/libs').mkdir()
    f.extractall('./tmp/libs')

cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=f'/tmp/libs/{filename}/instantclient_21_5')
```

## TLDR

Run this on your Linux machine (substitute your bucket name in the end):

```sh
wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-basic-linuxx64.zip
unzip instantclient-basic-linuxx64.zip
cd instantclient_21_5/
find . -type l -name "libclntsh.so*" -delete
mv libclntsh.so.21.1 libclntsh.so
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install patchelf -y
patchelf --set-rpath /tmp/libs/instant-client-basic-linux.x64-21.5.0.0.0/instantclient_21_5 instantclient_21_5/libclntsh.so
cd ..
wget https://src.fedoraproject.org/lookaside/pkgs/libaio/libaio-0.3.110.tar.gz/2a35602e43778383e2f4907a4ca39ab8/libaio-0.3.110.tar.gz
tar xzvf libaio-0.3.110.tar.gz
cd libaio-0.3.110
make prefix=`pwd`/usr install 
find ./usr/lib/ -type l -name "libclntsh.so*" -delete
mv ./usr/lib/libaio.so.1.0.1 ../instantclient_21_5/libaio.so.1
cd ..
zip -T -r instantclient-basic-linuxx64_patched.zip instantclient_21_5/
wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a9/b7/c2d0223fb4f1013b090cf82f3ce56f36f33b79a48f9c33b36717c2977b04/cx_Oracle-8.3.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
aws s3 cp instantclient-basic-linuxx64_patched.zip s3://<mybucket>/glue_libs/
aws s3 cp cx_Oracle-8.3.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl s3://<mybucket>/glue_libs/
```

Follow steps 9 and 10 above to configure your job.

Hope anyone who reads this will get this right on the first try, because I sure didn't.